# R console only shows text/comments

Tags: r

My R console seems to be stuck or something. It only shows the comments and doesn't execute the commands. I have had this more often. In the beginning R works fine and then at some point it stops working and only shows the comments. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you restart the session? `Session` -> `Restart R`

Comment: The problem doesn't go away when I do that unfortunately

Comment: I've just restarted it again and now it is stuck in the process of restarting (keeps saying "restarting R")

Comment: Can you update R to the latest version? You're using 4.0.3

Comment: I have updated it and now it seems to work again. I hope that was indeed the issue